# Kibana is stuck on "Kibana server is not ready yet"

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, elk

After installing Inhanced-Table plugin, my Kibana is stuck on the following message

```
  "Kibana server is not ready yet"
```

However after some minutes it completely became out of reach and I am facing with "Unable to connect" error on my browser.

I removed the plugin with the following command, but the error still exists.

```
./bin/kibana-plugin remove enhanced-table
```

Would you mind helping me in order to solve this problem. Also Kibana logfile is available via following link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LILdo07Q9r0-VNG7hgkbTOaE2eJzhQPs/view?usp=sharing

Thanks

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed a new clear kibana and problem fixed

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the log of your kibana, I've seen:

```
{ "type":"log",
  "@timestamp":"2020-11-11T05:44:01Z", 
  "tags":["fatal","root"],"pid":2884, 
  "message":"{ Error: Optimizations failure.\n   9263 modules\n    \n    
  ERROR in    ./src/legacy/core_plugins/console/public/np_ready/application/components/editor_example.js\n    
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../constants/help_example.txt' in 'D:\\Elastic\\Kibana\\kibana-7.6.1\\src\\legacy\\core_plugins\\console\\public\\np_ready\\application\\components'\n\n
```

So might be Kibana is still looking for the plugin, that's why the error occurred.

You should try stop kibana and start it again.

Comment: I did it but the problem is still exists